# Django Sorting a List inside a model

Tags: python, django, sorting, django-models

I want to keep a list of addresses sorted inside a table.

Here is the code for my sorting: (it doesn't work and honestly I have no idea how to go about this I'm new to Django/Python)

```
def detail(request, table_name):
    table = get_object_or_404(Table, name=table_name)
    addressSet = table.address_set.all();
    addressSet.sort(key=operator.attrgetter('address'))
```

Here is the models.py for these 2 items:

```
class Table(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    size = models.IntegerField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + " - " + self.description
class Address(models.Model):
    address = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    table = models.ForeignKey(Table)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.address)
```

Comment: You have a foreign key to RAMTable in Address.  If you want to have Address be related to Table, you should change that to (Table).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the ordering and many other options for a model through the use of the  [meta class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/options/). So for your example:

```
class Address(models.Model):
    address = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    ...

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['address']
```

This will order Address models in your queryset after they have been queried from the database. This will have no impact on how the data is underlying stored.